# SQL Primary Key Php and speed of the Query

Tags: php, sql, primary-key

I have a simple question but I couldn't found the answer on the internet.
I have a SQL table named result with only 2 fields : name and contents.
As every single name is unique I put my primary key on the field name.

What I want to do in Php is to specified a name and to get its contents :

```
$req = $bdd->prepare('SELECT contents FROM result WHERE name = :name');
$req->execute(array('name' => $inputName));
$donnees = $req->fetch();
$result=$donnees['contents'];
echo $result;
```

Of course this code works, but what I want to know is do I have to specify on my PHP code that name is the primary key or it already knows it and thus the execution speed of my query is at its maximum.

Thank you.

Comment: PHP neither knows nor cares about the primary keys on your database: that's the job of the database server

Comment: To add to the above, what you're doing is perfectly fine.  Your performance should be optimal as is.

Comment: ok thank you, actually I am testing this on a local server build with wamp and when I load the data through an .txt file the internet page is loading faster than when I use my sql database, is that normal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do premature optimization.

First you need a real world use case, then you need to profile/benchmark that in order to find the bottleneck and *then* think about what and how to optimize.

profiling sql queries can be done using `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` - but that won't be necessary for your simple query if name is already indexed.

In case you want to use this result table as a cache - that's probably not the best solution. Think about using a in-memory key value store like memcache.

Answer (score 0):

It's not php's work to handle primary (or any) keys of your database.
Your execution speed will be on its maximun since primary key implies that an index for this column will be created.